# Execute Oracle stored procedure from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am trying to run this C# code

```
string sql = @"EXECUTE GETEMPLOYEES1()";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, cnn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but I keep getting

> Invalid SQL error

My stored procedure code is very simple

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETEMPLOYEES1 
AS 
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Welcome to FYICenter!'); 
END;
```

I am able to run it normally by using `CommandType = StoredProcedure` but I need to execute some dynamic code entered by the user and it is vital to me to do it by `CommandType = Text`.

Comment: Do you need an additional ; on the end of your sql variable. ie. @"EXECUTE GETEMPLOYEES1();";

Comment: i just tried   string sql = @"CALL GETEMPLOYEES1()";   and that worked fine . I find that strange because i know EXEC should work   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXECUTE` is a SQL*Plus command. Use either

```
CALL GETEMPLOYEES1()
```

or

```
BEGIN GETEMPLOYEES1(); END;
```

Also if you choose command type StoredProcedure the library adds `BEGIN ... END;` internally for you.

`CALL` also requires empty parentheses when a procedure is parameterless.

Comment: you are right  , i was able to execute it with call , do you know how to do it when we pass a ref cursor to the proc also  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Welcome to FYICenter!');`  with `null;`, and see if that makes it any different. Im asuming in connection context there is no sense to try to output text, there is no console.